# I would like to retrieve alphanumeric values from a column in a table using SQL SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

I have a column with postal code and some of the rows have alphanumeric values. The table has 160 rows and out of the them there are 50 rows having alphanumeric values. So how can i write a query to select those 50 rows.

Ex: ABC50A
    kajf80G

Answer (score 2):

HANA supports PCRE compatible regular expressions. Just add a where clause like this:

```
postal_code like_regexpr '.*\p{L}.*'
```

This will find all rows where the postal code contains at least one letter.
If this is not what you are looking for, you have to be more specific which values schould be matched an which not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like_regexpr in where condition. But this will give you the records that only contain alpharumeric values.

```
     select idnumber, partner                                                 
       from "***"."BUT0ID" 
      where idnumber LIKE_REGEXPR '^[A-Za-z]+$'
   group by idnumber, partner;
```